# How to upload documents using Australian immigration website?

Tags: working-visas, immigration, australia

I got to the point where I have paid the application fee, and passed the health check. Now I have been asked to submit all the documents again however when I try to attach document I get an error...

[image]

I have already contacted them but it's been 4 days and no response, since I am proactive kind of person **is there a way to work around this problem?**

Comment: Are you applying for a tourist visa?

Comment: @JonathanReez Hi Jonathan, no Permanent working 189.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is!

You need to choose a file and then wait long enough (minutes) until file name changes from text to link, (it must be uploading in the background..).

[image]

You then can click 'Add attachment' and it uploads document correctly.

Hope this helps someone, as it has caused me substantial amount of unnecessary frustration.